# How to deploy only delta changes/files in different environments?

Tags: python, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-databricks

I need to deploy the delta or changes files in different environments. Need to build the artifacts accordingly.

I am using Azure DevOps and the target application is Azure Databricks Python Notebooks. Instead of full deployment of all the files every time, I want this to be only delta changes.

To implement CI/CD for Databricks code, I am using databricks CLI and the below command which will copy the files from GIT to the target databricks environment.

**databricks workspace import_dir**

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Pipeline, you can select which artifacts you want to download to the agent for a specific job and stage of the deployment. Typically, you will do this to improve the efficiency of the deployment pipeline when the tasks in that job do not require all or any of the artifacts for different environment, or if you implement custom code in a task to download the artifacts you require.  Please refer to [Artifact Download](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Frelease%2Fartifacts%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%23download&data=02%7C01%7Cv-liujxu%40microsoft.com%7C40fc898b5fd04ea2baef08d6f87c9428%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636969611287974588&sdata=yrH1P7va4dsQ8ogC4FO3w7X%2BexZHmntqrLp0manHGOc%3D&reserved=0).
You can also set [artifact variables](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Frelease%2Fvariables%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%26tabs%3Dbatch%23artifact-variables&data=02%7C01%7Cv-liujxu%40microsoft.com%7C40fc898b5fd04ea2baef08d6f87c9428%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636969611287974588&sdata=%2FlfUI8FzB2awlFye3b65zc7MnOvYH4aheKHaI477f2o%3D&reserved=0) of every artifact for changed files  to expose to download task,  the variables are accessible in the deployment tasks.